# .in not available in javascript gremlin?

Tags: javascript, database, graph, gremlin

I am able to make a query using .out and .both with javascript gremlin, but cannot make a .in query. Are there any workarounds to implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

The function `in` is a reserved word in JavaScript. In such cases the Gremlin clients suffix the step with an underscore. Try using `in_()` instead.